# Proper GTK+ widget for selecting file save location?

Tags: c, gtk

I'm trying to make a GTK+ interface in glade that has you select where to save a file. I tried using the GtkFileChooserButton widget, but when I run it, I get the warning

```
Gtk-WARNING **: gtk_file_chooser_button_set_property: Choosers of type `GtkFileChooserButton' do not support `GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SAVE'.
```

and the dialog wants me to pick a file to open, not save.

After some google searching, it sounds like it has been depreciated to use a GtkFileChooserButton to select where to save a file. From the mailing list post I found, it sounds like this was depreciated because it promotes bad interface design.

Right now, I can't seem to find the **right** way to do it though.

So, what is the right way have a user pick where to save a file? What about when they need to be able to pick more than one file?

Sorry if I have no idea what I'm talking about, this is my first time actually trying to do something useful with GTK+ and C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

/* Since You did not provide a version, assuming GTK+3 stable */

Afer a quick look at the [GTK+ reference manual](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/), quickly found that the manual says `GtkFileChooserButton` can only be used for selecting a file or a folder for opening. For saving it suggests using either `GtkFileChooserDialog`, or `GtkFileChooserWidget`. Which  one fits Your particular situation better, is up to You to decide. Consult with [the manual](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/) for more info. Also, the whole GTK+ API documentation is [**here**](http://www.gtk.org/documentation.php)

Actually, it's best to look at the manual first, and only then, if no relevant information is found, try to google it.

Comment: Thank you! And, yes, you guessed right on the Gtk version. I was using Gtk2 (something or other...), but then I ended up switching to gtk3 because I saw something about a file chooser in it in hopes of solving this on my own. Turns out it was even more depreciated in gtk3.